# How to create a random string in standard shell on hp-ux

Tags: shell, random, hp-ux

I need to create a shell script or a command that will produce random string, something like this:

```
date | md5sum
```

but it needs to work on default hp-ux installation, which doesn't contain any md5sum, there is neither /dev/random or /dev/urandom

Someone has an idea if that is even possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `BASH` OR `ksh` you can use `$RANDOM` variable:

```
rand=$RANDOM
```

Comment: wow, that's nice, now I just need to make a string from that somehow... but that should be easy

Comment: Yes just `rand=$RANDOM` is good enough. You can then use `$rand` as a string.